# node.js with underscore on linux Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-ec2, underscore.js, nvm

I am using amazon linux on ec2. Used nvm to install node v4.4.5 and run my script and i have this error:

> ```
> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
> ```

I tried to `npm install underscore --save` and `npm install underscore -g`. it just doesnt work.

i dont know why is wrong. can someone help?

> server-0 (err):     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>   server-0 (err):     at Function._load
>   (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
>   server-0 (err):     at Module.require (module.js:353:17) server-0
>   (err):     at require (internal/module.js:12:17) server-0 (err):
>   at Object. (/var/server/routes/v1/auth.js:6:11) server-0
>   (err):     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) server-0 (err):
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) server-0 (err):
>   at Module.load (module.js:343:32) server-0 (err):     at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) server-0 (err): Error: Cannot
>   find module 'underscore' server-0 (err):     at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15) server-0 (err):
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25) server-0 (err):     at
>   Function._load
>   (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:62:21)
>   server-0 (err):     at Module.require (module.js:353:17) server-0
>   (err):     at require (internal/module.js:12:17) server-0 (err):
>   at Object. (/var/server/routes/v1/auth.js:6:11) server-0
>   (err):     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) server-0 (err):
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) server-0 (err):
>   at Module.load (module.js:343:32) server-0 (err):     at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

Comment: check below the points may be you are in wrong  folder ,or may be you dont have Admin permissions